# Not able to insert data into mysql by using jsp

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, jsp

hi i am trying to insert data into mysql but not able to insert it.. here is my mysql database

[image: this is image name roseindia database and student as table]. there is no problem in database.

here is my code for 2 jsp file one is register.jsp which display page and another is insert.jsp which is for logic behind how to insert data.

Register.jsp

```
   <html>
<form method="post" action="insert.jsp">
<table>
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Confirm Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="cpass"></td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

insert.jsp

```
  <%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"%>

<%
String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
String lname=request.getParameter("lname");
String email=request.getParameter("email");
String cpass=request.getParameter("cpass");

        try{
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/roseindia", "root", "");
           Statement st=con.createStatement();
           int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into student(firstname,lastname,email,confirm_pass,) values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+email+"','"+cpass+"',')");
        System.out.println("Data is successfully inserted!");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        %>
```

what is problem with this code?

Comment: Why dont you use the servlets instead of `insert.jsp` and also print the query before execution it avoids mistakes

Comment: You get any exception ?

Comment: Where did you use the `ajax` here ?

Comment: Have you got any error?

Answer (score 4):

There is syntax error the last comma. Try to get rid of the last comma

```
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into student(firstname,lastname,email,confirm_pass) values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+email+"','"+cpass+")");
```

Answer (score -1):

you have mistake in insert query  remove it in last ,' from